# Prevent class A from creating an instance of class B

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, instance

#### Motivation

Say I have a class `Logger` that is used by numerous classes/projects to handle log messages.

Now, I'm implementing a new class `MyProcessor` that **cannot** use class `Logger` as is. It needs to internally change some `Logger` members for `Logger` to work as expected.

#### My approach

I generate a new class `MyLogger` that **extends** class `Logger` and add specific code in all the right places.

Now, class `MyProcessor` can create instance**s** of class `MyLogger` and enjoy the right functionality

#### Problem

A new member joined my team and needs to add code to class `MyProcessor`. He is not aware of the restriction that class `Logger` cannot be used directly in class `MyProcessor`

#### Solution

Let's prevent that on compile time: Make sure class `MyProcessor` is never creating instances of class `Logger`.

#### Notes

I know there are other approaches that will workaround my issue (such as, making `Logger` an abstract class and each derived class implement a set of virtual functions).
However, I'm more interested in resolving this issue specifically rather than different approaches.

Comment: You could put `#define Logger asdf` at the beginning of MyProcessor.cpp, thus intentionally breaking compilation if `class Logger` was used. But this would hardly be a nice, clean solution. Personally I don't think there is one, and there probably shouldn't be.

Comment: @KarstenKoop `#define Logger do not use class Logger in the file` might be a *slightly* more elegant version of this.  However there are two nice, clean, solutions:  1.  Fix `Logger` so it can be used from `MyProcessor`.  2. Code reviews.

Comment: I think an even easier approach is to do `#define Logger MyLogger` in `MyProcessor`. That way, everyone can use `Logger` (provided they both provide a similar creation process) but now the internals are hidden from whoever is using it

Comment: There is no generic way to exclude some class from using  your Logger, you can only achieve the opposite by 'friending' some definite set of classes and making vital Loggers methods private or protected

Comment: In your solution most likely you are going to violate Liskov substitution principle

Comment: @NarekAtayan agreed.

Comment: How about using `using Logger = MyLogger;` inside `MyProcessor`? This way you can use the type in the header as well AND restrict it to the class.

Comment: Another possibility might be to make the constructors of both loggers private and create a friend factory class that must be used for creation. Templates might help here.

Comment: What does it mean, that "`MyProcessor` cannot use `Logger`"? Is it ok, to call some function (maybe of another translation unit) that will work on a `Logger`? Is construction / deletion forbidden, or also usage of `Logger`?

Comment: @m8mble I mean that `MyProcessor` cannot use `Logger` as is since `Logger` will not work properly (unwanted behavior) for the use case of `MyProcessor`. `MyLogger` makes little adjustments in `Logger` for it to work as `MyProcessor` expects. I know it is a bit abstract but my real use case is much to complicated to be explained here. So the example here is a simple reduction of the problem.

Comment: @idanshmu What do you consider as usage? Method calls on `Logger`? `Logger` construction / deletion? Passing a `Logger` around (to some other function)? Please specify.

Comment: @m8mble In my case, using public member functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Logger {};

class MyProcessor
{
private:
    // If you get a compilation error using this, consult the lead.
    class Logger { Logger() = delete; };

public:
    void foo() { Logger nah; }
};

auto main() -> int { MyProcessor(); }
```

This is not “can't with some modest effort”, but “can't inadvertently”.